# Applying code only to the parent of the clicked element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, parent-child

How can I apply code only to the parent of the selected elements in JQuery and not for all ones?

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">

    <div class="box-li">
        <div class="hide"></div>
        <div class="click">click</div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-li">
        <div class="hide"></div>
        <div class="click">click</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.box-li .click').click(function(){
    $('.box-li .hide').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to go from an element to its parent. And to do that, you also need to use the `this` context - every callback assigns `this` to be the element it's currently the target. You can wrap it in a jQuery object `$(this)` and then traverse to the parent:

```js
$('.box-li .click').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

    <div class="box-li">
        <div class="hide"></div>
        <div class="click">click</div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-li">
        <div class="hide"></div>
        <div class="click">click</div>
    </div>

</div>
```